# jQuery Easy UI within JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle, jquery-easyui

Does anybody have any idea if it's possible to create a jsFiddle in which I can use the framework [jQuery Easy UI](http://www.jeasyui.com/)? I cannot choose jQuery Easy UI in the list of the frameworks.

Please let me know if that's possible and how I can do it please.

Comment: See the "Add Resources" option on the menu over as jsfiddle.

Comment: +1 for the link to an interesting jQuery library. Hadn't seen that one before (While I can see past it, their choice of fonts for their demo screenshots need help ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this [jsfidde link](http://jsfiddle.net/rW24a/) ?

[image: add js fiddle external resource]

You should select jQuery as your framework and the click the [add resources](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#add-resources) button and add the desired js and css (you can look at [this page](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php) to see what dependencies the demo has).
In your case, I think the resources are

```
http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js
```

and

```
http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for adding resources on jsFiddle: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#add-resources